# Swift 4 URLComponents Not Connecting Path Variable

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a Swift 4 project that I'm trying to learn a few new things and incorporate them at them same time, however I am stuck on something I just can't seem to work out.

```
import Foundation

protocol Endpoint {
    var baseUrl: String {get}
    var path: String {get}

    var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] {get}
}

extension Endpoint {
    var urlComponent: URLComponents{
        var component = URLComponents(string: baseUrl)
        component?.path = path
        component?.queryItems = queryItems

        return component!

    }
    var request: URLRequest{
        return URLRequest(url: urlComponent.url!)
    }
}

enum StoryEndpoint: Endpoint{

    case storiesList(type: String)

    var baseUrl: String{
        return "https://www.XXXXXXXXXXX.com/greeley"
    }
    var path: String{
        switch self {
        case .storiesList(let type):
            return "/api/items"
        }
    }
    var queryItems: [URLQueryItem]{
        return []
    }
}
```

Underneath `enum StoryEndpoint`, you can see I've set baseUrl, path, and queryItems, but if I run the project, it returns a custom error label defined in another file.

However, if I change:

```
    var baseUrl: String{
        return "https://www.XXXXXXXXXXX.com/greeley"
    }
```

To this (basically merging the baseUrl and path):

```
    var baseUrl: String{
        return "https://www.XXXXXXXXXXX.com/greeley/api/items"
    }
```

It returns the decoded items in my console correctly.

Have I set up something incorrectly with the urlComponent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate a `URLComponents` like this:

```
    var component = URLComponents(string: baseUrl)
```

It creates something like this:

```
[URLComponents]
    scheme: "https"
    host: "www.XXXXXXXXXXX.com"
    path: "/greeley"
    queryItems: nil
    ...
```

You see what happens if you execute `component?.path = path` after it.

```
[URLComponents]
    scheme: "https"
    host: "www.XXXXXXXXXXX.com"
    path: "/api/items"
    queryItems: nil
    ...
```

This may not be what you want.

You may need to write something like this:

```
    component?.path += path
```

(If you think considering `"/"` is sort of annoying, you may need to find other way around.)

Comment: That looks like it worked. I appreciate your suggestions and will work on this. Thanks!

Comment: How do I get the URL out of this ?

Comment: Please check the reference of [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlcomponents).

Comment: SearchEndpoint.fetchResults("sss").urlComponent.url 
Got it something like this worked. Thanks